# HTTP POST request to PHP REST API using Flutter

Tags: php, flutter

So I have been at this for way way too long but I just can't figure out why this isn't working what I'm trying to do is send some JSON post data to an existing PHP REST API that I've created and then read that JSON data like `$_POST["username"]` and I can't really change how the API works as it's used by another application which it works perfectly with so it's something to do with my flutter code but I'm not sure what as I started learning it today.

My flutter code:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

http.Response response = await http.post(
    'https://path.to.php.file',
    headers: <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
      "formname": "login",
      "username": globals.currentUsername, // value = futurelucas4502
      "password": globals.currentPassword, // value = password
      "datetime": DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(DateTime.now()) // MySql Datetime format
    }),
  );

  debugPrint("Response: " + response.body);
  debugPrint("Status: " + (response.statusCode).toString());
```

Cut down PHP code:

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    echo file_get_contents('php://input');
    echo '<br>';
    echo $_POST["username"];
?>
```

Output:

```
Response: {"formname":"login","username":"futurelucas4502","password":"password","datetime":"2020-05-12 00:01:33"}<br><br />

<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: username in <b>/storage/ssd2/545/12156545/public_html/temp/index.php</b> on line <b>7</b><br />

Status: 200
```

What can I change in my flutter code to make this work?

**EDIT:** Just for clarity I do want to handle an application/json request the only reason `file_get_contents` is there is to test if the PHP API was actually receiving the data.

Comment: you can't get only the username value in your php script , is that right ?

Comment: The PHP code is quite confusing. Do you want to handle an `application/json` request or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`? The `file_get_contents('php://input')` suggests the former but `$_POST["username"]` suggests the latter. You cannot have both. What does this _other application_ use?

Comment: I want to use application/json and $_POST["username"] but thank you i have a solution now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you should just be sending a urlencoded form, rather than JSON encoding the post data.

Try:

```
body: <String, String>{
  "formname": "login",
  "username": globals.currentUsername, // value = futurelucas4502
  "password": globals.currentPassword, // value = password
  "datetime": DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(DateTime.now()) // MySql Datetime format
},
```

Comment: that results in 
```Exception has occurred.
StateError (Bad state: Cannot set the body fields of a Request with content-type "application/json".)```

Comment: So, remove that header, which makes sense, as you are not sending JSON, so should not be setting the content type.